# Using UserManager in a Blazor Webassembly hosted application and Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I have [followed the instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and have a Blazor Webassembly application that is authenticating against Azure Active Directory successfully.

In the documentation, [there is a section pertaining to UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usermanager-and-signinmanager), which (to me at least) implies that `UserManager` can be used with Blazor Webassembly apps that authenticate against Azure Active Directory.

I have added the following snippet to `Program.cs` as the documentation says...

```
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => 
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

...however the documentation doesn't show how to implement UserManager. The documentation does include a sample controller with `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` injected, but not how to register it.

The sample uses `ApplicationUser` which I'm guessing is a custom class. I've tried using `UserManager<IdentityUser>`, which I'm guessing ApplicationUser would inherit from, but get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'SimonADAuthenticatedWASMHostedApp.Server.Controllers.WeatherForecastController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method26(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

The way in which I've registered UserManager before is by using an IdentityDbContext. Would I still have to do this even though I'm using Azure Active Directory? Or is there another way of registering UserManager?

I've tried giving as much information as I can. I will do my best to give any more if needs be. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65397622/7687666)

Comment: Thank you for the resource! Microsoft Graph API is what I was looking for in order to interact with AAD users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http